# find all elements that have a class of X and show them?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find all elements within my page that have a CSS class of `value` and then show them (by default they are hidden)

So far I have the code below but I'm getting errors.

```
var elements = $(this).hasClass("value");
for(var item in elements) {
  item.
}
```

How is this done correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".value").show()
```

Shows all elements which have the class `value`. If you have set them to `display: none;`, you could also use:

```
$(".value").css("display", "block")
```

Depends on how you have hidden the objects.

**Edit:**
If you need to show multiple classes, just do:

```
$(".value1, .value2, .value3").show()
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that, there may be more than one class applied to an element, 1, 2 or 3 could be applied

Comment: How do you mean? something like `<span class="class1 class2 value">` ? or do you wan't to show all elements which belong to `value1` or `value2` for example?

Comment: yeah like your exampple, i would need to find value in a list of multiple classes, Thanks